# How do I change the style of the infobox for a KML layer on google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'd like to bring in some data using a KML layers in google maps and it looks like google take the hard work out of clicking on each data point and showing the 'title, description, etc' for me, because of this though there is no options to define the style of an info box like normal.

Does anyone know how you can define the style of an info box that comes as part of introducing a KML layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this might help you.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-georss

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/docs/reference.html

Comment: Thanks, I had another look and they call them 'ballons' in this guide which is why i was missing them.